# php spl_autoload didn't work with namespaces that are syntax errors

Tags: php, namespaces, syntax-error

I get this example from 
http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.spl-autoload.php#92767

But this causes an error 
*Fatal error: spl_autoload() [function.spl-autoload]: Class space could not be loaded in C:\my_projects\site.local\www\index.php on line 18*

**/index.php**

```
// Your custom class dir
define('CLASS_DIR', 'oop/classes');

// Add your class dir to include path
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.CLASS_DIR);


// You can use this trick to make autoloader look for commonly used "My.class.php" type filenames
spl_autoload_extensions('.class.php');

// Use default autoload implementation
spl_autoload_register();

new space/my;
```

**/oop/classes/space/my.class.php**

```
namespace space;
class my{
  public function __construct{
    var_dump('space class was here!');
  }
}
```

I know about PSR-0, but in my case I need to understand how built function works

Comment: although you know about PSR-0, I wanted to add the link for those who don't know: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md

Comment: Never copy and paste code if you want to learn something new. Type it yourself. That works like magic for our brain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new space/my;
```

should be

```
new space\my;
```

Note: you missed `()` of the `__construct` in `my.class.php`

Comment: Yes, the problem needs basic debugging first, e.g. logging errors and checking them. But you didn't note that in your answer which I think is somewhat misleading then. Because this could be any other syntax error related problem as well (and not only these specific two).

Comment: Sure that's correct PHP, I added an answer that explains it in detail. But it is still an error in the syntax because it's not what OP wanted to do. I also showed how to debug the build in loading of `spl_autoload_register` in that answer.

Comment: Also, for the second error you highlight, I think it actually *is* a syntax error in php or something like a parse error, unexpected something.

Answer (score 2):

The following line of code is likely to be a syntax error because you did not use the language syntax as you might have thought:

```
new space/my;
```

Let's take it apart what we have here:

- `new` - the [`new` keyword](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.basic.php), we use it to instantiate a new object.
- `space` - the name of the class, here the string `"space"`.
- `/` - the [division operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).
- `my` - the (undefined?) constant `my` which will result into the string `"my"` if undefined.

Because of that just being so (that is the language), PHP naturally tries to instantiate the class `space` and then tries to devide it with the string `"my"`. Example:

```
$object = new space;
define('my', 0);
$result = $object / my;
```

Because of you using autoloading and the class `space` non-existence you see the fatal error.

So strictly spoken the syntax error is not in PHP but by using the wrong syntax (here: `/` instead of `\` which is the correct symbol to separate namespaces).

Hope this is helpful. Take care that PHP has loose typing so an existing class that could have been instantiated [would have produced probably a division by zero warning](http://codepad.org/5Yd16ku6).

*Debugging `spl_autoload_register`:* As this is an internal function when used with no autoloader callback function, you can extend it with the following for debugging purposes:

```
spl_autoload_register(funcion($class) {
    echo 'Autoloading class: ', var_dump($class), "\n";
    return spl_autoload($class);
});
```

Also you might want to *add* your extension(s) instead of overwriting the existing ones:

```
($current = spl_autoload_extensions()) && $current .= ',';
spl_autoload_extensions($current . '.class.php');
# .inc,.php,.class.php
```